# Regex to extract multiple values from javascript-like-array-string

Tags: regex

I have following string

```
(...)

api_images = ['/files/a.jpg','/files/avd.jpg','/files/5.jpg'];
api_titles = 3;
api_descriptions = 42;
```

I need a regex to extract the values from braces `[]` like this:

- `/files/a.jpg`
- `/files/avd.jpg`
- `/files/5.jpg`

String is long, and can contain few arrays, so regex has to match the word `api_images`, and seek between the braces.

Please help.

Comment: What regex flavour? You ask for "seek between braces" - is recursion required? E.g. what shall this return: `[['a'],'b',['c','d']]`

Comment: no, no recursion. i need to get api_images values but i cannot evaluate it - it has to be regex on script tag content.

Comment: ah, and flavour is PRCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PCRE doesn't support [variable-length look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), I think you should do this in two passes; first find these "arrays" and then extract the strings.

Finding the arrays is not too hard (this is the raw regex, escape as needed):

```
\[(?:[^\]\['"]+|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*\]
```

This will give you the array as matches like this:

```
['/files/a.jpg','/files/avd.jpg','/files/5.jpg']
```

Which can then be parsed nicely using a JSON parser, or by using another regex for finding/extracting the strings:

```
(?<=')[^']+(?=')|(?<=")[^"]+(?=")
```

This will give you the string values. Note: these regex don't account for escapes in the string (e.g. `'that\'s a problem'` would not be parsed right).

Comment: this lookahead and lookbehind is what i needed, but I'll have to find a way to add searching of this "api_images = [" before matching group. And You have to exclude commas with quotes.

Comment: if You have idea how to match this in single pass - please post it here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Single pass is probably not possible with PCRE. As for matching the "api_images" string, just append that in the front of the first pass regex: `api_images\s*=\s*\[(?:[^\]\['"]+|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*\]` - the second pass will find the strings fine even if that additional text is there. As for excluding commas with quotes, if in the second pass you continue the match two characters ahead of the end of the previous match you'll be fine.

Comment: i just found out that there is even simpler way of doing this: `'([^']+)'`, but as Yours - it doesn't support finding the api_images.

Comment: This last regex will match any string in single quotes, not limited to being part of an array.

Comment: I didn't said that it will, just saying that it works same as yours `(?<=')[^']+(?=')|(?<=")[^"]+(?=")`.

Comment: Sure it will, but it stores the output as a capture, and it doesn't support double quotes. You could also use the fancier `(["'])((?:\\.|(?!\1).)*)\1` and take the 2nd capture; this would allow for both single and double qutoes and also support escapes in the string (e.g. `\'`).

Answer (score 0):

If from many lines of text, you want to fetch the line starting with `api_images` and ignore all the other lines, you can use this.

**Flow:**

1. Fetch all the lines starting with `api_images` till the line-ending.
2. Remove unwanted characters.
3. Split the string at `,`.
4. Process as desired.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$str = "api_images = ['/files/a.jpg','/files/b.jpg','/files/c.jpg'];
    api_titles = 3;
    api_descriptions = 42;
    api_images = ['/files/1.jpg','/files/2.jpg','/files/3.jpg'];
    api_titles = 3;
    api_descriptions = 42;";

//Find all the lines starting with "api_images"
preg_match_all("/(api_images.*)/", $str, $matches);
$api_images = $matches[0];

$count_api_images = count($api_images);
for($i=0;$i<$count_api_images;$i++){
    $api_images[$i] = str_replace("api_images = [", "", $api_images[$i]);
    $api_images[$i] = str_replace("'", "", $api_images[$i]);
    $api_images[$i] = str_replace("]", "", $api_images[$i]);
    $api_images[$i] = str_replace(";", "", $api_images[$i]);
    $api_images[$i] = explode(",", $api_images[$i]);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($api_images);
echo "</pre>";
```

?>

Each string, i.e.`/files/a.jpg`, `/files/avd.jpg` `/files/5.jpg` etc can be accessed by `$api_images[0][0]`, `$api_images[0][1]`, `$api_images[0][2]` and so on.

[Live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cs0cae)

Comment: Of course one can use some JSON Parser or CSV parser instead of this crude `str_replace` method.

Comment: sorry, I cannot use anything else than regex in this particular field.

Comment: Oh, then please add some relevent code in your question, which you already have tried/written (with or without regex, working or not), and we can start from there.